# Excel process does not close

Tags: vb.net, excel-2010

I have this sub in my class that just opens excel to see if a range is present.  The problem I am running into is that the process just does not close.  I've been googling my tail off and I can't find a resolution.  Please take a look at my code and see if it something simple stupid that I am missing.  Thanks.

```
Private Function NamedRangeExists(ByVal ProductFileName As String, ByVal RangeName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    'Create an Excel Object
    ExcelApp = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
    Dim TheRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name
    Dim TheRangeName As String = ""
    Dim ObjWorkbook As Excel.Workbooks = ExcelApp.Workbooks

    'Open the Product
    Dim TheProduct As Excel.Workbook = ObjWorkbook.Open(ProductFileName)

    For Each TheRange In TheProduct.Names 'ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Names
        TheRangeName = CStr(TheRange.Name)
        If (InStr(TheRangeName, RangeName) <> 0) Then
            TheProduct.Save()
            TheProduct.Close()
            ExcelApp.Quit()
            ExcelApp = Nothing
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp)
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    TheProduct.Close()
    ObjWorkbook.Close()
    ExcelApp.Quit()

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ObjWorkbook)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(TheProduct)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp)
    TheProduct = Nothing
    ObjWorkbook = Nothing
    ExcelApp = Nothing
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.Collect()

    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Have you come across [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/a98b7675-c2d5-4036-bbde-53a3b88a4df5/) in your Google search?

Answer (score 1):

For any future viewers, this is the general method that I use:

```
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet = xlWB.Worksheets(1)

    'do stuff

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    FinalReleaseComObject(xlWS)
    xlWB.Close(False)
    FinalReleaseComObject(xlWB)
    xlApp.Quit()
    FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp)
```

You'll need `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`.

Any other declared Excel objects (such as `TheRange` in the OP's case) will need to be set to `Nothing` before garbage collection.

The sequence of commands shown here is important. A detailed explanation can be found [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=160433).

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job! [Documentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=finalreleasecomobject&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx&ei=mf1FUazwK8LIyAHU_YHIAw&usg=AFQjCNHqqrsPpl1xZSkHfpUSZm4yFPS6_w&bvm=bv.43828540,d.aWc)

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj)
```

Comment: I added the following and still have the same issue.
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ObjWorkbook)
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(TheProduct)
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelApp)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have something left over from before? That method has never failed me.

Comment: Yep.  Excel does not initialize until the very top of this sub.  Until the program reaches that point, there is no excel interaction.

Comment: I meant anything in the task manager process list from earlier files opening and not being removed.